# How to simulate xmlHttpRequests in a laravel testcase?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

**Updates see below**

My controllers distinguish between ajax and other requests (using `Request::ajax()` as a condition). That works quite fine but I wonder if there is a way of unit testing the controllers handling the the requests. How should a test look like? 
Something like this probably but it doesn't work ...

```
<?php

    class UsersControllerTest extends TestCase
        {


            public function testShowUser()
            {
                $userId = 1;
                $response = $this->call('GET', '/users/2/routes', array(), array(), array(
                    'HTTP_CUSTOM' => array(
                        'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
                    )
                ));


            }
        }
```

**Update**

I kind of found a solution. Maybe. Since I am not interested in testing the proper functionality of the Request class (very likely all native classes provided by Laravel, Symfony, etc. are enough unit tested already) best way might be to mock its ajax method. Like this:

```
        public function testShowUser()
        {

            $mocked = Request::shouldReceive('ajax')
                ->once()
                ->andReturn(true);
            $controller = new UsersCustomRoutesController;
            $controller->show(2,2);
        }
```

Because the real `Request` class and not its mocked substitute is used when using the `call` method of the `Testcase` class I had to instantiate the method which is called when the specified route is entered by hand. But I think that is okay because I just want to control that the expressions inside the `Request::ajax()` condition work as expected with this test.

Comment: Good question - [the code](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/587f35513761547e43c4538e44df485f62fcd92e/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.php#L1590) used to detect if it's an AJAX request does indeed simply check the very header you are setting.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to prefix the actual header with HTTP_, no need to use HTTP_CUSTOM:

```
$server = array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest');
$this->call('get', '/ajax-route', array(), array(), $server);
```

Alternative syntax which looks a bit better IMO:

```
$this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
$this->call('get', '/ajax-route');
```

Here are some similar code examples for JSON headers (`Request::isJson()` and `Request::wantsJson()`):

```
$this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');
$this->call('get', '/is-json');

$this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_ACCEPT', 'application/json');
$this->call('get', '/wants-json');
```

Here's a useful helper method you can put in your TestCase:

```
protected function prepareAjaxJsonRequest()
{
    $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');
    $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_ACCEPT', 'application/json');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried it out and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: I can't get `$this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');` to work on a POST

Comment: Works fine here, I just tested on a fresh install.

Comment: Can you throw together a pastebin with the code showing your test and controller?

Comment: There is nothing that isn't already included in the answer. With the before mentioned `setServerParameter`, `Request::isJson()` returns true.

Comment: what does $this->client refer to?

Answer (score 7):

Here's the solution for Laravel 5.2.

```
$this->json('get', '/users/2/routes');
```

It's that simple.

---

Intenally, `json` method applies following headers:

```
'CONTENT_LENGTH' => mb_strlen($content, '8bit'),
'CONTENT_TYPE'   => 'application/json',
'Accept'         => 'application/json',
```

Answer (score 3):

**In Laravel 5:**

```
$this->get('/users/2/routes', ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);
```

Then you can chain the normal assertions:

```
$this->get('/users/2/routes', ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'])
    ->seeJsonStructure([
        '*' => ['id', 'name'],
    ]);
```

Comment: `->assertStatus(302)`, 302 in this case is a redirect

Answer (score 2):

```
$server = array('HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest');
$request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request($query = array(),$request = array(), $attributes = array(), $cookies = array(), $files = array(), $server , $content = null);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Laravel 5.X

As an addition to already existing answers, and for **clarity** purpose you can add those helper methods to your **TestCase**

```
<?php

namespace Tests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase as BaseTestCase;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    use CreatesApplication;

    // ...

    /**
     * Make ajax POST request
     *
     * @param  string $uri
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse
     */
    public function ajaxPost($uri, array $data = [])
    {
        return $this->post($uri, $data, ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);
    }


    /**
     * Make ajax GET request
     *
     * @param  string $uri
     * @return \Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestResponse
     */
    public function ajaxGet($uri)
    {
        return $this->get($uri, ['HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest']);
    }
}
```

---

### Usage

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        $response = $this->ajaxPost('/user', ['name' => 'Sally']);

        $response
            ->assertStatus(201)
            ->assertJson([
                'created' => true,
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On Laravel 8 you could modify the header like this:

```
$response = $this->withHeaders([
        'HTTP_X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest',
])->get(route('route_name', ['key' => value]));
```

Do whatever you want to do with $response.