# How to load routes based on application/json header in Laravel

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, phpunit

I'm using the `application/json` header to control how my controller acts when a request is received.  I need for the POST in my unit test to include an `application/json` header.

I've tried:

```
public function testStore()
    {
        $this->validator
            ->shouldReceive('validate')
            ->once()
            ->with($this->attributes)
            ->andReturn(true);

        $this->repository
            ->shouldReceive('create')
            ->once()
            ->with($this->attributes)
            ->andReturn($this->entity);

        $this->controller
            ->shouldReceive('creationSucceeded')
            ->once()
            ->with($this->entity);

        $this->client->request('POST', 'shared/users', [], [], [
                'HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'
            ], json_encode($this->attributes));

        $this->assertResponseStatus(201);
    }
```

And it the `Request::isJson()` in my controller continues to return false.

I also tried using `'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json'` instead of the `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` above.

Comment: sorry did not realize test methods ..check  this link,it may help.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20093897/how-to-simulate-xmlhttprequests-in-a-laravel-testcase

Comment: @ytsejam - Thanks for posting.  Unfortunately, using `$this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');` doesn't work for me, whether it be a GET, DELETE, POST or PUT request.

Comment: how does your shared/users look like? the request can is not tied to the response http-content-wise.

Comment: What about HTTP_Content-Type ?

Comment: How did you setup the routing based on the content-type

Comment: @kapad See the answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my case, I was using `Content-Type` to determine which controllers to load.  This didn't work for me, because routes are loaded into memory when `TestCase->createApplication()` is run.  This means my headers had no effect.

I ended up making a `RouteInflector` that allows me to force my tests to use the Api routes.

```
class ApiTestCase extends TestCase
{

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public static function setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        /**
         * Routes are loaded into memory before tests are run.
         * Because of this, we can't have routing logic based on
         * heads.  Using the RouteInflector we can override
         * header to createApplication() and must use a constant
         * to force the RouteInflector to use Api controllers.
         */
        RouteInflector::isJson(true);
    }

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        //Lets do this right
        $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');
        $this->client->setServerParameter('HTTP_ACCEPT', 'application/json');
    }

}
```

Inflector:

```
class RouteInflector
{

    /** @var bool */
    protected static $isJson = false;

    /**
     * Review the request details and determine which controller
     * subpackage should be used.

     * We could also check the request source to help determine the
     * package.
     *
     * Defaults to Web.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getControllerSubpackage()
    {
        if (self::isJson() || Request::isJson()) {
            return 'Api';
        }

        return 'Web';
    }

    /**
     * Used by tests to tell routing that the current request
     * is a json request.
     *
     * @see \Tests\ApiTestCase
     *
     * @param bool|null $isJson
     *
     * @return bool Only provided if parameter is null
     */
    public static function isJson($isJson = null)
    {
        if (is_null($isJson)) {
            return self::$isJson;
        } else {
            self::$isJson = $isJson;
        }
    }
}
```